# Taking differences along time axis for the data with irregular overpass time

Tags: geospatial, python-xarray, satellite-image

I wonder how to take differences along the time axis of data with the **irregular overpass time** with Xarray.

**Data:**

- NASA SMAP L3 soil moisture data, regularly gridded
- Irregular overpass time. Two- or three-daily, depending on the overpass. Missing daily values are filled with NaNl.

**What I want to do:**

Calculate the difference of the soil moisture data along the time axis, ignoring NaN data. For example, in pandas dataframes, I can achieve it by dropping NaN data and take the diff(). Now I want to do it in Xarray; however, an element-wise drop is not supported in Xarray, so I am at a loss.

**What I tried:**

- Simply taking diff(). The resulting values end up in full of NaN because missing daily values are filled with NaN.
- Forward-filling the NaN data and taking diff(). This successfully calculates the differences that I want. However, I lose time information; the original time corresponding to the data becomes unclear, which I need for the next step.
- Looking into Sparse Array package ... but I didn't find anything helpful to calculate diff().

I am looking for any algorithms or workaround!

Comment: Does `da.ffill().diff().where(da.notnull())` do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately, I don't think so, da.notnull() will pick up the calculated differences at the starting point of ffill(), so the results is going to be zero. 

`ds: [0.3 NaN NaN 0.4]`
`ds.ffill(): [0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4]`
`ds.ffill().diff(): [0 0 0.1]`
And `where(ds.notnull())` takes the first 0

Comment: Or right. You may want to use .shift to move the notnull result by one

Comment: The time interval is not regular, so shift does not work either (sometimes it needs to be shifted 2days, sometimes 4 days)

Comment: Oh but you could shift -1 to pull the notnull back from the second value no?

Comment: Do you mean ds.ffill().diff().where(ds.notnull()).shift(-1)? I'll try

Comment: Okay it worked!! Thank you so much. Also I had to use "bfill". `xr_test.bfill(dim="time", limit=5).diff(dim="time").where(xr_test.notnull().shift(time=+1))`

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelDelgado. Do you want to add answer to this Q, or shall I do it?

Comment: You got it :) glad it worked!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to count the number of days backfilled? I want to get dz/dt

Comment: Sure - similarly you can use isnull. Something like `non_nulls = ds.isnull().cumsum(dim='time'); non_nulls - non_nulls.where(ds.notnull()).ffill()` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you so so much! It worked perfectly and now I can calculate dz/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelDelgado here is the answer.

```
da.bfill(dim="time").diff(dim="time").where(da.notnull().shift(time=+1))
```

Another note: I also dug into sparse array, but there was no good solution to it.

Comment: What do you mean by the sparse array comment? Did you see https://sparse.pydata.org?

Comment: Yes, I meant pydata/sparse or scipy.sparse. I wasn't sure if I could do diff on sparsearray.data only along time axis + in xarray setting

Comment: xarray supports using pydata/sparse as a backend - so you can initialize a sparse array and then set it as the dataarray’s data and use it as you normally would an xarray object

Comment: Yes but still diff() is not simple (ie. can't do da.diff()), and still have to use some tricks

Comment: Oh right yeah that’s true. The original data comes as a regular sparse grid? What’s the storage format?